# unnumbered chapter doesn't show up in the header

Tags: book-design, front-matter, book-class

I am working on a book wherein there's an unnumbered chapter after the ToC and before the numbered chapters.

Here's the `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[twoside,a4paper]{geometry}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
        \addtocounter{tocdepth}{-2}
        \tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter*{unnumbered-chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]\par
\chapter{1st Chapter}
\lipsum[11-30]\par
\chapter{2nd Chapter}
\lipsum[21-40]\par
\end{document}
```

In the resulting PDF file, the unnumbered chapter has the header "CONTENTS".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV2rj.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI59e.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x5cf.png]

**Question 1: Why does this happen?** I want the header to show "unnumbered-chapter". The page number is showing the Arabic numerals, which is right.

**Question 2:** Can someone also show me how to include "Foreword", "Preface"
and "Introduction" with the same reflecting in the header and with roman numerals?

Thanks in advance.

**Please feel free to edit the question title/question content/tags to make it/them relevant.**

Comment: Most classes never send any data from `\chapter*` to the headers. You'll have to do it manually using something like `\markboth{unnumbered-chapter}{unnumbered-chapter}`

Comment: where should I add this line? after \chapter*?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. Can you please answer **Question 2** also? If you can make both answers into a solution, I can mark them as answered.

Comment: Q2: place them inside the frontmatter (that's where they belong), and use `\chapter`, within `\frontmatter` the `\chapter` command is not numbered, but the title automatically goes to the header and the TOC.

Comment: That solves my questions. Thank you so much. If you can make both comments as an answer, it will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for question (1): In most classes `\chapter*` (and friends) writes neither to the headers or to the TOC. To add a title to the header use something like

```
\chapter*{Title}
\markboth{Title}{Title}
```

As for question (2): There parts of your document belongs inside the `\frontmatter`, there just use `\chapter{Title}`. Under `\frontmatter` sectional numbering is disabled but `\chapter{Title}` of course still writes to the headers and the ToC.

The subsequent `\mainmatter` then brings the sectional macros back to "normal".